# can sqlite databases be different if every table is the same?

Tags: sqlite

I created two SQLite databases. I compared them with diff and they differed.

Then I did a SQLite3 text dump using `SELECT * FROM foo` for every table for both databases. They all matched.

What else could differ between the databases? Is there data about my data stored somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite data format is not fully distinguished. There can be any number of very different files that contain the same data. For one thing, deleted records inside the file can differ.